# Regex digits smaller then 82

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a simple regex but I don't know why it is not working.

User enter 2 digits number like `01`, `09`, `23`, `55`, until `82`. After `82` system will refuse.

Here is my regex, 2 digits must be smaller than 82.

```
0[1-9]|[1-8][0-9]|8[0-2]
```

Comment: I think you can also simplify it to `[0-7]\d|8[0-2]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have `[1-7]` for the range 10-79, not `[1-8]`. Don't forget the `^` and `$` to specify the start and ending of the string:

```
^(0[1-9]|[1-7]\d|8[0-2])$
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Normally I have ^ and $ sign.

Comment: Btw what if i try to do for example 34HOLLAND<br/>I wrote this one but it didnot work again.<br/>new Regex(@"^(0[0-9]|[1-7][0-9]|8[0-2]|[a-zA-Z]){0,25}$");

Comment: I mean starts with digits and after 2 digits starts with character and end with character.

Comment: But if I just enter string it is also working. I dont want that. It will work if it starts with digit and end with character. Can u help me about that?

Comment: @kad1r: I don't understand what the problem is. I tried `Regex.IsMatch("34HOLLAND", @"^(0[0-9]|[1-7][0-9]|8[0-2]|[a-zA-Z]){0,25}$")` and it returns `True`.

Comment: Thanks for patience Guffa. But if you enter just HOLLAND it works to. But it shouldn't. It will works if and olny if you enter 2 digits and characters. I mean, if you just enter 34 it wont work, if you enter holland it wont work, but if you enter 34holland it will work.

Comment: @kad1r: Then put them after each other in the expression: `^(0[0-9]|[1-7][0-9]|8[0-2])[a-zA-Z]{1,25}$`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry about my alot of questions.

Answer (score 4):

Why not cast to an integer and then just test `x < 82`?

Answer (score 1):

Your second part is wrong. It'll match from 10 to 89, whereas you want it to match from 10 to 79 and let the third part handle 80 to 82.

```
0[1-9]|[1-7][0-9]|8[0-2]
```